# Volume bar is in 0 position , but there is sound when start playing http streaming video of iphone

Tags: iphone, http, streaming, volume

When we start play streaming video via url via mpmovieplayer , wolume bar is in 0 position , but there is sound when start  playing http streaming video .
Pls advice us how to solve this . Thanks !

Comment: sofar this doesn't sound programming related. Is this your own app, or a genaral 'howto use my iPhone question'?

Comment: Thanks lexu . However this is mpmovieplayer in our app related question . I just want to know how to position right of volume bar when mpmovie player make sound while streaming . THere is nothing I can control . Pls advice us . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set and change volume using this way.

```
UISlider *slider_volumeControl=[[UISlider alloc] init];
slider_volumeControl.minimumValue=0;
slider_volumeControl.maximumValue=1;
[slider_volumeControl setValue:0];
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:self.slider_volumeControl.value];
```

Write method like this for slider value change event

```
-(IBAction)changeVolumeOnSliderValueChange:(id)sender
{
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:self.slider_volumeControl.value];
}
```